# Java checked exception not in the function's throw specification?

Tags: java, exception, java-native-interface, throws

Normally, the Java compiler confirms that all checked exceptions that are thrown are in the throw specification.  Does anything special happen when a native function throws a java checked exception that was not in the functions throw specification list, or does is the throw specification list simply ignored at runtime?

C++

```
void function(JNIEnv * env, jclass jc) {
    jclass newExcCls = env->FindClass("java/lang/NullPointerException");
    env->ThrowNew(newExcCls, "ERROR");
}
```

Java

```
public class Tester {
    static {
        System.loadLibrary( "MyLibrary" );
    }        
    private static native void function();
    public static void main(String [ ] args) {
        try {
            function();
        } catch( Exception e ) { //is it caught? Or what happens?
            e.printStackTrace();
        }        
    }
}
```

(The C++ function name would probably be mangled.  Also loadLibrary should be in a try catch.  Don't care, I don't believe it's relevant to the problem.  There's possibly other errors in the code, but they're probably not relevant either.)

Comment: I'm kinda surprised this isn't a duplicate.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You don't even have to resort to native code to fool the checked exception mechanism. See the [Javadoc on Thread.stop(Throwable)](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/api/java/lang/Thread.html#stop%28java.lang.Throwable%29). I was once left wondering for the entire day how my code threw an `InterruptedException` in the middle of code that did not declare it. I didn't even find the answer then, but now I know :)

Answering your immediate question: yes, the checked exception logic is a compiler-only feature and ignored at runtime.

Comment: The function you linked is not a great example, since it only throws unchecked exceptions as far as I can see, which do not have to be in the throw specification list.

Comment: Read the following sentence, then: "The thread represented by this thread is forced to complete whatever it is doing abnormally and to throw the Throwable object obj as an exception."

Comment: Oh, missed that sentance, I was looking for Exception class names.  Interesting find.